# Como descontar los dias del fin de semana

Tags: php, mysql

tengo el siguiente código donde cuento la diferencias de días, pero quiero descontarle los fines de semanas

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime($machine->fechasolicitud);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($machine->fecha);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a días');
?>
```

Hay alguna forma en PHP o en MySql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una aproximación en php con fechas en formato date es con un bucle que recorre el periodo y pregunta por el día de la semana:

```
$counter = 0; 
$fecha1= "2018-01-01"; $fecha2 = "2018-01-31"; //ejemplo de fechas
for($i=$fecha1; $i<$fecha2; $i = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i ."+ 1 days"))) {
   if (date("w",strtotime($i)) != 5 && date("w",strtotime($i)) != 6) { $counter++;}
}
echo $counter;
```

Comment: hola, funciona bien pero la resta entre el `2018-02-26` y `2018-02-13` resultado es 10 pero debiera ser 9

Comment: Es por $i<=$fecha2, cambialo por $i<$fecha2

Comment: Muchas gracias! Denuevo hehe

Comment: Siempre un placer ;)

Comment: Muy agradecido, el tema del `$( ".div-calcular" ).data( "calcular", atotal[j]);` del otro post que realice hice lo me  dijiste pero igual no funciona. Si realizo un alert(atotal[j]); me muestra la suma pero no me la agrega al div

Comment: @MoteCL me lo anoto para mirarlo mañana que hoy no llego

Comment: Muchas gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo un poco más automatizado tomando como referencia la respuesta de carmen puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```html
<?php

$fsis = date("Y m d h i a");

list($sano, $smes, $sdia, $shora, $smin, $sap ) = explode(" ", $fsis);


$contador = 0; 
$fecha = new DateTime();
$fecha->modify('last day of this month');


$fecha1 = $sano . "-" . $smes . "-" . $sdia; $fecha2 = $sano . "-" . $smes . "-" . $fecha->format('d');
for($i=$fecha1;$i<=$fecha2;$i = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i ."+ 1 days"))) {
   if (date("w",strtotime($i)) != 5 && date("w",strtotime($i)) != 6) { $contador++;}
}
echo $contador;


?>
```

Así tomas las fechas del servidor y las restas con la fecha del mes que esta en curso, que si bien unos meses pueden traer 31 días otros meses no, así dejas el proceso automatizado para cualquier mes del año, puedes restarlo con el día actual y si lo que quieres es restar el mes global puedes eliminar la variable sdia para que te tome el día 1 solamente.

Espero te sirva a ti y a la comunidad que lo necesite, saludos.